# "yum groupinstall" i686 packages on x64?

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I'm working on enabling x64 host build workers to build i686 RPMs, now that AWS EC2 (which we use to run build workers) is deprecating i386 nodes like m1.medium in favour of x64-only instance types like m3.medium.

I could roll a custom AMI that runs a 32-bit userpsace on a 64-bit kernel, but this seems like a good opportunity to switch to using multiarch for builds.

I currently install the core dev tools and package build dependencies with

```
yum install yum-utils
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum-builddep postgresql
```

... but I can't figure out how to do the multiarch equivalent. For individual packages you just:

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

for example, but this won't work for groupinstall or builddep.

Ideas?

Comment: BTW, `multilib_policy=all` [per this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/512791/102814) works for "groupinstall" but not `yum-builddep`.

Comment: Why aren't you using koji, or at least mock? It sounds like you tried to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MichaelHampton We're building packages for many different distros, and running a lot of tests as well as doing packaging. Distro-specific tools are great when you're building lots of packages for that distro / package format. Much less so when you're doing cross-distro releases of a few packages. As for mock: I was completely unaware of it. It looks very useful.

Comment: They will handle at least RHEL/CentOS and Fedora. If you're trying to build for SuSE, no guarantees.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'll check it out. SuSE isn't a target of interest. It won't help us with the package building for Debian/Ubuntu, OS X, Windows, etc (which is why I've been using Jenkins to control jobs) and doesn't seem to support EC2 dynamic build worker provisioning etc - but mock looks useful, at least.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I I could +100 a comment, I would. Thankyou very much for the pointer at mock; incredible life-saver, and needs a "see also" in the rpmbuild man page. I may well land up using koji for all the RPM distros targeted too, and just deal with using sbuild or something separate for deb distros. (I wish I could just lock 'em all in one room and let the last package format standing leave).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you can use `multilib_policy=all` for groupinstall, and use setarch command for yum-builddep like this:

```
setarch i686 yum-builddep postgresql
```

Comment: Ah, that's the trick. Thankyou.